# python 3.2 and pirateradio on wheezy

Tags: raspbian, python

My RPi runs a Raspian wheezy, and I've got python 3.2 installed. I'd like to run this script to make my RPi transmit FM: https://github.com/Make-Magazine/PirateRadio.

I've done `git clone https://github.com/Make-Magazine/PirateRadio.git` and attempted to start the script with python3.2.

**Edit:** I got some error messages due to a misplaced `pirateradio.conf`, which were solved by the answer below, but I have new error messages now, possibly to a misconfigured `pifm`.

I've installed `pifm` by unzipping the contents of http://omattos.com/pifm.tar.gz into a folder named `pifm` and moving it to `/root/pifm`. Now, when I `sudo python3.2 PirateRadio.py`, I get the following:

```
  File "PirateRadio.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "PirateRadio.py", line 31, in main
    setup()
  File "PirateRadio.py", line 150, in setup
    run_pifm()
  File "PirateRadio.py", line 156, in run_pifm
    fm_process = subprocess.Popen(["/root/pifm","-",str(frequency),"44100", "stereo" if play_stereo else "mono"], stdin=music_pipe_r, stdout=dev_null)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 745, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1371, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Why is the OS not granting permission, to which process, and what can I do to make it run smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Your config file is probably missing.  Make sure the file `/pirateradio/pirateradio.conf` exists and is a valid config file.

The path is hard coded in the source so if you want to use a different file you will need to edit `PirateRadio.py`

The reason you this happens is that the program uses [ConfigParser.read()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read) to load the configuration which ignores missing files instead of raising an error.

Note: I linked to the Python 2 docs but Python 3 behaves the same way.

Comment: This was indeed the case. I changed the source to look in the same directory as the `PirateRadio.py` file.